# The effect of multiple comparisons on confidence of individual tests

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I am wondering how the confidence of each individual test in a block of multiple comparissons is affected.

example: if i make 100 tests with 95% confidence, the probability of an error in the whole block is bigger. I am wondering how this affects the confidence of this 100 tests chosen at random. Meaning, if I take one test, does the 95% confidence interval change somehow or does it stay the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Multiple comparisons is a complicated topic, difficult to understand at first. I think you'll get better answers if you write a more detailed question. For each probability you ask about, specify exactly what you mean. For every probability specify the  numerator (what counts as a "success") and a denominator (what are you counting).